# SQL Server Management Studio keyboard shortcuts are not working (particularly Edit.GoToDefiniton)

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2017

I have installed SQL Serever Management Studio 17.6. There are necessary for me to use Edit.GoToDefiniton - F12 shortcut, but it does not work. 
If refer to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-keyboard-shortcuts?view=sql-server-2017) there is such shortcut, but actually no.

[image]

Comment: Could  you tell what is actually displayed? (what's the selected symbol and the displayed details)

Comment: Are you sure that ability exists in SSMS? I went to `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Environment` -> `Keyboard` and typed `Edit.GoToDef` into `Show commands containing` and it returned no results.

Comment: @Larnu, this functionality has described in the topic  'SQL Server Management Studio Keyboard Shortcuts'. This was available in previous version of SSMS. I think must be in new version. Why we have described feature without it's implementation?